# Add translation on server side only using next-i18next

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, i18next, react-i18next, next-i18next

**Scenario:**

- We have a server that responds to several domains (70+)
- Each domain has it own language (already in an individual JSON file)
- I have a map `"domain":"translation.json"`
- Each client has a single language: a user visiting "example.com" will see the website in English only. A visitor in "example.es" will see it in Spanish. There are no options to change language of the current site, just link to another domain.

**Problem**

I don't want to load 70+ translations in the client side because the client will never be able to change it.

How can I apply that map in my NextJS app but not drop the other resources to client?

PS: there is no tag for "next-i18next" here on SO (and there are 2 for nextjs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next-i18next has 2 modes,

1. Server side, it loads the relevant translation file using [`i18next-node-fs-backend`](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-node-fs-backend)
2. Client side, it loads the relevant translation file using [`i18next-xhr-backend`](http://i18next-xhr-backend).

That means by default, this lib loads **only** the relevant language.

Comment: Should I init the i18next + use(node-fs-backend) in `_app.js`? I'm a bit lost here

Comment: No, next-i18next does it for you, pls go to the examples folder of this lib, run it, check what you get.